# Geometry problem solved with too advanced techniques?

Tags: geometry

> A circle rests in the interior of the parabola with equation $y=x^2$
>   so that it is tangent to the parabola at two points. How much higher
>   is the center of the circle than the points of tangency ?

I've seen the solution of the problem [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1070117p4650627) on Aops site and it left me a bit skeptical.

I am not referring to the validity of the solution,which is correct, but rather to the fact that the problem has been solved using basic calculus.

Now, I came across this problem on Aops 2 volume book which doesn't teach any calculus,so it's clear that there's a simpler solution to the problem that relies only on basic geometry;however I've not been able to find it...

So I am asking if someone knows a solution which involves only basic geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need calculus for this one. Let the points of tangency be $(\pm a, a^2)$ and the center of the circle be $(0,c)$.  Then the radius of the circle, $r$, is given by the Pythagorean theorem: $$r^2 = (c-a^2)^2 + a^2.$$ We can now plug this into the equation for the circle, $x^2 + (y-c)^2 = r^2$, to get: $$x^2 + y^2 - 2cy + c^2 - (c-a^2)^2 - a^2 = 0$$ but then we have $y=x^2$ so we get $$x^4 + (1-2c)x^2 + c^2 - a^2 - (c - a^2)^2 = 0.$$ We want the circle to only have two points of tangecy with the parabola, so we want the discriminant to $=0$, i.e. $$1 - 4c + 4c^2 - 8a^2c + 4a^4 + 4a^2 = 0$$ so that $$c = a^2 + \frac{1}{2}.$$ So now the answer to the question is simply $$a^2 + \frac{1}{2} - a^2 = \frac{1}{2} .$$

Comment: +1 but a typo in $r^2=a^4+(1-2c)a^2+c$, it should be   $r^2=a^4+(1-2c)a^2+c^2$

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I think it's all cleaned up now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a name -- "The Quadratic Circle".

To solve it, we need knowledge slightly beyond simple geometry. They are :- (1) The theory of quadratic equation; and (2) Analytic geometry on circles.

[image]
$y = x^2$ .............(1)

From given, $K$, the center of the unit circle must lie on the y-axis. Thus, $K= (0, k)$ for some $k$.

Then, the equation of that circle is
$x^2 + (y – k)^2 = 1^2$  .............(2)

Putting (1) in (2), we have
$y + (y – k)^2 = 1$

:
:

$y^2 + (1 – 2k)y + [k^2 – 1] = 0$  ..........(3)

Let the points of intersection of the two curves be at $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

By symmetry again, $y_1 = y_2$.

That means (3) has equal roots.

∴ $(1 – 2k)^2 – 4(1)[k^2 – 1] = 0$

:
:

∴ $k = \dfrac {5}{4}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mick

Comment: @Mr.Y Hope that helps.